# Changing the rest_url_prefix make basic auth doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I'm using **JWT Authentication for WP REST API** plugin with Basic-Auth plugin to use the WP Rest API.

I wanted to change the base url for security but when I change it with `rest_url_prefix` filter, Basic auth doesn't work in POST, etc..

How to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that for current versions of WordPress, using the json_url_prefix filter no longer works.

On WordPress 4.7 (and using the REST API from the core instead of a plugin), this is what you have to do to change the API prefix.

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', 'my_theme_api_slug'); 
function my_theme_api_slug( $slug ) { return 'api'; }
```

If this doesn't work straight away, you'll need to flush the rewrite rules. You can run this piece of code once to do so (don't leave it in your code so it runs everytime)

```
flush_rewrite_rules(true);
```